# JUnit test in Isolation using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have basic understanding of how to apply Mockito framework.
But when it comes to some real time scenarios I failed to write tests in Isolation(by Mocking the dependent classes).

Can you help me to write Unit test for PriorityQueuePrinter class by Mocking PriorityQueue Implementation(BinaryMaxHeap.java).

I wrote testPriorityQueue() with BinaryMaxHeap object, in this case my test becomes success but I want to achieve the same to mock BinaryMaxHeap so that my test will be Isolate. I think I have to set method behaviours also in my test method.

In short, Priority Queue is the Implementation for BinaryHeapTree and Printer class uses Priority Queue.

Below are the code classes.

```
public interface PriorityQueue<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    int size();
    void insert(T element);
    T popMax();
}




public class BinaryMaxHeap<T extends Comparable<T>> implements PriorityQueue<T> {

    private ArrayList<T> items;

    public BinaryMaxHeap() {
        items = new ArrayList<T>();
    }   

    public int size() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public void insert(T element) {
        items.add(element);
        shiftUp();
    }

    public T popMax() {
        if (items.size() == 1) {
            return items.remove(0);
        }
        T hold = items.get(0);
        items.set(0, items.remove(items.size()-1));
        shiftDown();
        return hold;
    }

    /*
     * place newly added element in correct position in binary tree
     */
    private void shiftUp() {
        int k = items.size() - 1;
        while (k > 0) {
            int p = (k-1) / 2;  // get parent element index
            T child = items.get(k);
            T parent = items.get(p);
            if (child.compareTo(parent) > 0) {
                // parent and child are not in correct position, need to swap
                items.set(k, parent);
                items.set(p, child);
                k = p;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void shiftDown() {
        int k = 0;
        int l = 2*k+1;  // left leaf node
        while (l < items.size()) {
            int max = l;    // assume left node as max element
            int r = l+1;    // right leaf node
            if (r < items.size()) { 
                if (items.get(r).compareTo(items.get(l)) > 0) { 
                    max++;  // identify max element in leaf nodes
                }
            }
            T parent = items.get(k);
            T child = items.get(max);
            if (parent.compareTo(child) < 0) {
                // parent element is less than leaf node, need to swap it
                    T temp = items.get(k);
                    items.set(k, items.get(max));
                    items.set(max, temp);
                    k = max;
                    l = 2*k+1;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
 }

public interface Printer {
    public <T extends Comparable<T>> String asSortedString(T... values);
}

public class PriorityQueuePrinter implements Printer {

    private PriorityQueue priorityQueue = null;

    public <T extends Comparable<T>> PriorityQueuePrinter(PriorityQueue<T> priorityQueue) {
        this.priorityQueue = priorityQueue;
    }

    public <T extends Comparable<T>> String asSortedString(T... values) {

        //PriorityQueue<T> priorityQueue = 
        addElements(values);
        //return getSortedElements();
        return null;
    }

    private <T extends Comparable<T>> void addElements(T... values) {
        //PriorityQueue<T> priorityQueue = new BinaryMaxHeap<T>();
        for (T element : values) {
            priorityQueue.insert(element);
        }
        //return priorityQueue;
    }

    public int size() {
        return priorityQueue.size();
    }

    private String getSortedElements() {
        StringBuilder sortedElements =  new StringBuilder();
        boolean isFirstElement = true;
        while(priorityQueue.size() > 0) {
            if (!isFirstElement) {
                sortedElements.append(",");
            }
            isFirstElement = false;
            sortedElements.append(priorityQueue.popMax());
        }
        return sortedElements.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String a[]) {
        PriorityQueuePrinter p = new PriorityQueuePrinter(new BinaryMaxHeap<Integer>());
        String sortedElements = p.asSortedString(1,4,6,3,2);
        System.out.println(sortedElements);
    }
}
```

Below is the sample test code tried but not able to complete.

```
public class PrinterTest {
    @Mock
PriorityQueue<Integer> mockPriorityQueue;   // mock object
PriorityQueue<Integer> priorityQueue;

@Test
public void testPriorityQueueWithMock() {

    PriorityQueuePrinter printer = new PriorityQueuePrinter(mockPriorityQueue);
    String s = printer.asSortedString(5,3,6);
    assertEquals("6,5,3", s);
}

@Ignore
public void testPriorityQueue() {
    priorityQueue = new BinaryMaxHeap<Integer>();
    PriorityQueuePrinter printer = new PriorityQueuePrinter(priorityQueue);

    String s = printer.asSortedString(5,3,6);

    assertEquals("6,5,3", s);
}

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("==tearDown==");
}
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        //mockPriorityQueue = new BinaryMaxHeap<Integer>();
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is your problem? If you get the exception, please post it

Comment: I don't have any clue to write test for PriorityQueuePrinter class in Isolation by Mocking PriorityQueue. If I create plain PriorityQueuePrinter object I was able to write test case for asSortedString(...) method. Same behaviour I have to achieve with Mock object.

Comment: remove the setUp() method, remove @Mock, and init your mockPriorityQueue as Mockito.mock(PriorityQueue.class)

Comment: @Nadir, what is the benefit will I get If I do above setup. Anyways both are same ways to create Mock object.

Comment: I you're using annotations, also use the mockito runner, to not have to take care of manually calling MockitoAnnotations.initMocks. Anyway, you got your priorityQueue mocked, all seems good. Not really sure what your problem is.

Comment: Mocking priorityQueue is not just enough, perhaps I have to set expected behaviour for methods inside priorityQueue so that my test will be Isolate. I failed to do this step. I hope my question will be clear now.

Comment: yes, if you expect to receive something from priorityQueue methods, you should use Mockito.when(queue.something()).thenReturn() prior to calling your queue printer. And if you want to verify that queue methods were called use Mockito.verify(queue).something() after calling printer method